# Does optimization remove unnecessary `cend()` calls?

Tags: c++, c++11

How many times would `myVector.cend()` be called at runtime:

```
    std::vector<int> myVector;

        // ...

    for (auto it = myVector.cbegin(); it != myVector.cend(); ++it)
    {
       // ...
    }
```

It should be called either once or `myVector.size() + 1` times, but I'm not sure how much we can expect the compiler to optimize things here. Because of that, I almost always add beforehand:

```
const auto end = myVector.cend();
```

and fix the loop this way:

```
for (auto it = myVector.cbegin(); it != end; ++it)
```

Comment: Use a [range based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and then you know it is only called once.

Comment: Do it in the simpler way to read, until your profiler tells you that it needs to change.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of range based for loops. I agree that my example is poor, but I would still be interested in the answers.

Comment: Why do you think cend() is more expensive than a variable load?

Comment: Your code guarantees that cend() will be called one more times than necessary.

Comment: If you *really* want to know what the compiler does, then inspect the generated asm.

Comment: @JesperJuhl ....for every *possible* implementation?

Comment: @Kyle Strand possibly. Depending on your curriosity level.

Comment: I've removed the "best practices" part of the question, because such questions are considered off-topic here. I've also replaced your title with one that actually describes the question (which is very important and possibly why you received a downvote). Don't worry that the question has been marked as a duplicate; it's still a reasonable question, just one that happens to have a potentially hard-to-find duplicate.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm going to go ahead and assert that asking here is actually a better solution than that.

Comment: @Kyle Strand Sure. Fine with me. But inspecting the code the compiler *actually* generates really is the only way to know for sure. And every C++ developer worth his "salt" should be able to read a bit of asm. So I don't think it's an unreasonable comment.